# Why was she inside a glass room all the time?

Tags: character, blade-runner-2049

In *Blade Runner 2049* why Dr. Ana Stelline was inside a glass room all the time?

Why was she not allowed outside, how does she contact with outside world?

Comment: Isn't [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/81260/why-is-this-character-in-a-bubble) the same question, essentially?

Comment: @Walt I agree - same question.

Answer (score 5):

I believe she had a weakened immune system. The room was sterile, with no viruses or bacteria. If she was outside of the room, the viruses and bacteria would infect her (because of her weak immune system) and she would die. The rest of the population - like us - are immune to typical viruses and bacteria.

She could contact the outside world the same way that I'm doing right now:  from a computer. She could also use a phone, or any other high-tech electronic communication device they had in 2049.